# google map marker not showing why?

Tags: google-maps

I'm following google map api and add the following code but not showing the marker

```
function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(27.7000, 85.3333);
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.7000, 85.3333),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Hello World!"
        });
        // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
        marker.setMap(map);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What does your HTML/css look like?  How big is your map_canvas div? Any javascript errors?

Comment: 100% width and 400px height map is showing but not marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating your map after adding the marker to it, so it is null at that point

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

    marker.setMap(map);
```

you might have some javascript errors so look at the console log

Comment: yeah, I was at that mistake.